# Как при создании приложения JavaFx сделать из jar файл exe

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea

**Всем доброе утро, день или вечер.**
Интересует такая проблема, совершенно недавно занимаюсь изучением языка (буквально месяца 3) и решил сделать для подруги приложение по ортодонтии на базе JavaFx.
Используя 18JDK и Idea я создаю проект
[image: Создание приложения]

Далее создалась вся основа после чего на основе SceneBuilder создал макет, прописал контролер для приложения.
[image: Макет проекта]
После этого аргументировал что приложение в среде запускается
[image: Само приложение]
Создаю артефакт jar
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Далее использую Launch4j и на выходе получаю кучу ошибок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Понимаю что проблема в том, что скорее всего используются библиотеки с новой JDK или проблема в модулях Maven.
Но не знаю как решить эту проблему. Пытался сделать через 11JDK тоже самое.
Заранее спасибо за помощь новичку!

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Попробуйте скомпилить на java8, classfile version 52.0 - это java8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть очень удобный мини-инструмент [JPackageScriptFX](https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX)  для сборки проектов в exe (jlink + jpackage). Скрипт удобен в показательности настроек. Сам скрипт в виде 3-х вариантов для разных ОС в каталоге jpackagefx-main. Это самое удобное решение для модульных решений и решает вопрос конфликта версий.